# K-fold Cross Validation Implementation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

i am currently using a LGBM regressor model to predict Unit Sales of products across different stores and i want to perform K-fold Cross Validation.

I am using the following code:

```
model_lgb_base=lgb.LGBMRegressor(objective='regression',)
model_lgb_base.fit(x_train,y_train)

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
cv = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=42, shuffle=False)

accuracy = cross_val_score(estimator=model_lgb_base, X = x_train, y = y_train, cv=10, scoring = 'r2')
print(accuracy)
accuracy.std()

#Predicting the test set results
y_pred = model_lgb_base.predict(x_valid)

[0.77916146 0.78209908 0.78333999 0.78286847 0.7831663  0.78029406
 0.78534152 0.77421018 0.78810446 0.77937227]
```

Am I using this correctly? I want to train the model using 10 fold cross validation and  return the best model.

Comment: You only try one model, so how can the procedure return the "best" one? `cross_val_score`, as seen, just returns a score value for each one of the K folds (here 10) for diagnostic purposes.

Comment: @desertnaut Oh yeah thanks, I see now I phrased it wrong. I am looking to see wheather my model overfits in any way and for that reason i am doing K-fold. I want to do it on all my models (LGBM, RF, XGB) in order to see which model consistantly performs best. Thanks for the reply. I also want to know how my K-fold partitions the data, since i never state it except in my train_test_split (20% tts). What is the percentage split in corss_val_score?

Comment: Please **edit & update** your question to clarify *exactly* what you ask - comments are not the right place for this. That said, CV is not used for overfitting detection.

Comment: @desertnaut Ok sorry, im new to this stuff and was looking for some help

Comment: Aren't we all? We are trying to help you getting your question in a status most likely to get an *answer*. But you need to help *us* in this.

Comment: @desertnaut Of course. But does the reason for using k-fold cv change the question? I just wanna know if that is the right way to implement K-fold cross validation. Regardless of my reasons for using Kfold CV. Not trying to sound like an asshole here sorry. Just confused (Edit - I think ive found something on stackoverflow that can help me.) Thanks  for helping us noobs  des:)

Comment: There is not *one* single way to implement CV; it depends on *why* you would want to do so, i.e. what exactly you are trying to achieve (CV can be used for many different purposes). If that helps, what you show here is not wrong, and it is a valid approach (save for that, as already said, you will not get back any "best" model, only a performance assessment of your single one). Does this really answer your question?